# jQuery Seating Plan

Tags: jquery, json

I'm trying to iterate over this JSON to create a table. There's 3 elements within the JSON, seats, rows and seatprice. Each td needs to have an id based on the rows and how far along the row it is (ie, each number 1 is a seat, so the count would need to be added to them). It also has to add the pricelookup data as a class so that there can be different prices for the seats clicked.

```
var data =     {
    "who": "RSNO",
    "what": "An American Festival",
    "when": "2013-02-08 19:30",
    "where": "User Hall - Main Auditorium",
    "seats": [
        "00000000000000000011111111111111000000000000000000",
        "0000000000000001111111111111111aaa0000000000000000",
        "00000000000000aa111111111111111aaaaa00000000000000",
        "00000000000001111111111111111111111111000000000000",
        "000000000aa00aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa1100aa000000000",
        "00000001111001111111111111111111111100111100000000",
        "00000aaaaaa0011aaaaaaaaa11111111aaa1100aaaaaa00000",
        "00001111111001111111111111111111111100111111100000",
        "000aaaaaaa110011111111111111111111110011aaaaaaa000",
        "00111111111100111111111111111111111001111111111000",
        "00aaaaa1111110011111111111111111111001111aaaaaaa00",
        "11111111111100111111111111111111111001111111111110",
        "0aaaaaaaaaaaa001111111111111111111100aaaaaaaaaaaa0",
        "01111111111110011111111111111111110011111111111100",
        "00000000000000001111111111111111110000000000000000",
        "01111111111111001111111111111111100111111111111100",
        "01111111111111001111111111111111110011111111111110",
        "01111111111111001111111111111111100111111111111100",
        "00a11111111111100111111111111111100111111111111a00",
        "00111111111111100111111111111111001111111111111000",
        "00011111111111110011111111111111001111111111111000",
        "00111111111111100111111111111111001111111111111000",
        "00011111111111110011111111111111001111111111111000",
        "00011111111111110011111111111110011111111111110000",
        "0000000111a111111001111a1111a110011111111110000000",
        "00000000111111110011111111111110011111111000000000",
        "00000000001111111001111111111110011111110000000000",
        "00000000000000111001111111111100111000000000000000"
    ],
    "rows": [
        "DD",
        "CC",
        "BB",
        "AA",
        "Z",
        "Y",
        "X",
        "W",
        "V",
        "U",
        "T",
        "S",
        "R",
        "Q",
        "P",
        "N",
        "M",
        "L",
        "K",
        "J",
        "H",
        "G",
        "F",
        "E",
        "D",
        "C",
        "B",
        "A"
    ],
    "seatPrice": [
        "                  00000000000000                  ",
        "               0000000000000000000                ",
        "              0000000000000000000000              ",
        "             0000000000000000000000000            ",
        "         00  000000000000000000000000  00         ",
        "       0000  00000000000000000000000  0000        ",
        "     000000  000000000000000000000000  000000     ",
        "    0000000  00000000000000000000000  0000000     ",
        "   000000000  0000000000000000000000  000000000   ",
        "  0000000000  000000000000000000000  0000000000   ",
        "  00000000000  00000000000000000000  00000000000  ",
        "000000000000  000000000000000000000  000000000000 ",
        " 000000000000  00000000000000000000  000000000000 ",
        " 000000000000  0000000000000000000  000000000000  ",
        "                000000000000000000                ",
        " 0000000000000  00000000000000000  0000000000000  ",
        " 0000000000000  000000000000000000  0000000000000 ",
        " 0000000000000  00000000000000000  0000000000000  ",
        "  0000000000000  0000000000000000  0000000000000  ",
        "  0000000000000  000000000000000  0000000000000   ",
        "   0000000000000  00000000000000  0000000000000   ",
        "  0000000000000  000000000000000  0000000000000   ",
        "   0000000000000  00000000000000  0000000000000   ",
        "   0000000000000  0011111111100  0000000000000    ",
        "       0000000000  111111111111  0000000000       ",
        "        00000000  1111111111111  00000000         ",
        "          0000000  111111111111  0000000          ",
        "              000  00000000000  000               "
    ],
    "priceLookup": [
        10,
        20
    ]
}

$(data.seats).each(function (index, element) {
$('#plan').append('<tr><td> ' + element[0] + ' </td></tr>');
})
```

So far, it creates just the first column, and only the seatlayout, not the other datas. Any help would be appreciated. My main problems are trying to get this to work with both rows and columns.

Comment: So is there an actual question? You seem to be on the right path...

Comment: Woops, sorry. My actual question is how would I get this to work with both rows and columns as opposed to just columns, with a view to then figuring out the other two parts

Comment: What's the significance of the `a` character (as opposed to `0` or `1`) in the `data.seats` strings?

Comment: @Barney "a" is a seat that is already booked. 1 is free seats, 0 is no seats. I can use a nested if statement to sort them out later (they're ultimately replaced with images)

Answer (score 1):

How I would approach this:

1. Parse all the data into your own data structure
2. Use your own data structure to generate the view

There are several ways to do #1, but a quick and dirty way of  handling this is having an object to hold a Row, which would hold a bunch of Seat objects, and your Rows  live in a Event  structure in a "seating chart" property. To get fancy, you could abstract it out further and have a Venue which has the seats and rows, and then the Event has the pricing and so on, but we'll be simple!

For #2, you can do this a million ways, but by keeping parsing the model and drawing separate, you can change how it's displayed very easily.

So given the JSON above, we can create our Event and drawing code pretty easily:

```
// function that retuns an "event" object with a seating model
var event = function (data) {
    // so we can get price information...
    var priceLookup = data.priceLookup;
    // helper function to create an empty, named row
    var createRow = function (rowName) {
        return {
            name: rowName,
                seats: []
        };
    };
    // helper function to make a seat object
    var createSeat = function(seatNumber, index, priceCode, booked) {
        return {
            price: priceLookup[priceCode],
                seatNumber: seatNumber, // the nth seat in the row
                index: index, // we might have empty spaces before us...
                reserved: booked
        };
    };

    // function that combines all our data into one structure
    var createSeating = function(data) {
        var rows = [], i;
        // for every row in our data set...
        for (i = 0; i < data.seats.length; i++) {
            console.log("Creating row number %d, which is row %s", i, data.rows[i]);
            var row = createRow(data.rows[i]); // make a row with the right name
            // now iterate over every position in the 'seats' string and make seats 
            // and create a counter for what the number of the actual seat is...
            var seatCount = 0;
            for (var s = 0; s < data.seats[i].length; s++) {
                console.log("Looking for a seat at index %d", s);
               var seatStr = data.seats[i].charAt(s); 
               if (seatStr === "1" || seatStr === "a") { // we are a seat!
                   console.log("... and we found one!");
                   seatCount += 1;
                   var booked = seatStr === "a";
                   // create a Seat and add it to our row
                   row.seats.push(createSeat(seatCount, s, data.seatPrice[i].charAt(s), booked));
               }

            }
            // add our row to the rows array
            rows.push(row);
        }
        return rows;

    };
    // create and return an object that describes our event
    return {
        venue: data.where,
        eventTime: data.when,
        performer: data.who,
        name: data.what,
        seating: createSeating(data)
    }
}

// this function takes the "seating" of an Event and can draw it
var drawSeating = function(seating) {
    // an array of ROW objects
    for (var i = 0; i < seating.length; i++) {
        row = seating[i];
        console.log("Drawing row %s", row.name);
        // now iterate over our seats...
        for (var s = 0; s < row.seats.length; s++) {
            var seat = row.seats[s];
            console.log("Drawing seat number %d which is at index %d and costs %s", seat.seatNumber, seat.index, seat.price);
            // you could output a view with all the relevant information in DATA attributes
            // like: <div class="seat" data-row="row.name" data-seatnum="seat.seatNumber" data-price="seat.price"  data-reserved="seat.reserved">
            // and use the index of the current seat and the index of the previously draw
            // seat to add spacing as needed.
        }
    }
};


// get an event model given our data
var myEvent = event(data);

// now we can draw it's seating chart!
drawSeating(myEvent.seating);

// add other methods to draw ui like
// drawPageheader(myEvent)
// or what have you.
```

I didn't actually draw the view out full for you there, but you can see in the comments how you can add HTML `data` attributes to whatever element you wind up using to draw the actual seat in to contain all the relevant data. You could also generate an ID based on row and seat index as well.

EDIT: you commented on what "a" meant in your chart, so I modified to incldue that